# save current date in custom format to oracle Db

Tags: java, date

I want to save date ie.current date in oracle DB in MM/dd/yyyy format.

My oracle db has column , which has data type as date.

can anybody let me know how I can do this. I tried like,

```
java.text.DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
String s = df.format(new Date());  // It is giving in String format
```

But How I can set it to my oracle DB column ?

Comment: show your code to work with DB ( prepared statement? )

Comment: You really _don't_ want to do that.  The column then becomes useless for sorting.  Store it as a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP and format it when you query the table.

Answer (score 1):

Just save the date without any formatting.

```
update table set column=sysdate where id=1
```

While reading back the data, use

`select to_char(column, 'MM/DD/YYYY') my_date from table`